# Php error after upgrading to Assets 2

Tags: assets, upgrade

After upgrading assets most pages work fine, but I do have problems with empty assets entries. When viewing such a page the following error occurs:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'unknown_source' in .../expressionengine/third_party/assets/libraries/assets_lib.php:1188 Stack trace: #0 .../expressionengine/third_party/assets/ft.assets.php(1114): Assets_lib->instantiate_source_type(Object(stdClass)) #1 [internal function]: Assets_ft->pre_process('{filedir_3}foto...') #2 .../expressionengine/libraries/api/Api_channel_fields.php(350): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 .../expressionengine/modules/channel/mod.channel.php(3790): Api_channel_fields->apply('pre_process', Array) #4 ...expressionengine/modules/channel/mod.channel.php(323): Channel->parse_channel_entries() #5 .../expressionengine/libraries/ in .../expressionengine/third_party/assets/libraries/assets_lib.php on line 1188

I've managed to solve this by re-saving all entries that cause the conflict. Since this is not a huge site that was doable. But it might be worth knowing what's the cause.

It's an MSM site, 2.4.0

Comment: Please send bug reports directly to the developer - thanks!

Comment: Where's the restriction here? A lot of EE questions are bug (upgrade issues, php errors etc) related. It could be that there's a solution or workaround which serves other people facing the same issue?

Comment: Bug reports, especially for add-ons which offer official support here (and thus are well-maintained), are rendered moot very quickly (when the bug is fixed), and do not contribute to a vibrant Q&A site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will be fixed in an upcoming release - apparently we didn't think of everything :)